# Python vs IPython cProfile sort_order

Tags: python, sorting, ipython, cprofile

lovers,

When running "cProfile" in "IPython" I can't get the "sort_order" option to work, in contrast to running the equivalent code in the system shell (which I've redirected to a file, to be able to see the first lines of the output). What am I missing?
E.g. when running the following code:

```
%run -m cProfile -s cumulative myscript.py
```

gives me the following output (Ordered by: standard name):

```
9885548 function calls (9856804 primitive calls) in 17.054 seconds
Ordered by: standard name
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(DeprecatedOption)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(RegisteredOption)
    6    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 <string>:1(non_reentrant)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:2(<module>)
   32    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:8(__new__)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageFilter.py:106(MinFilter)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageFilter.py:122(MaxFilter)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageFilter.py:140(ModeFilter)
```

... rest omitted

The IMO equivalent code run from the system shell (Win7):

```
python -m cProfile -s cumulative myscript.py > outputfile.txt
```

gives me the following sorted output:

```
9997772 function calls (9966740 primitive calls) in 17.522 seconds
Ordered by: cumulative time
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.116    0.116   17.531   17.531 reprep.py:1(<module>)
    6    0.077    0.013   11.700    1.950 reprep.py:837(add_biorep2treatment)
 9758    0.081    0.000    6.927    0.001 ops.py:538(wrapper)
33592    0.100    0.000    4.209    0.000 frame.py:1635(__getitem__)
23918    0.010    0.000    3.834    0.000 common.py:111(isnull)
23918    0.041    0.000    3.823    0.000 common.py:128(_isnull_new)
```

... rest omitted

I also noticed that there is a difference in the number of function calls. Why?

I'm running Python 2.7.6 64bit (from Enthought) and have made sure that the exact same version of python are used for both executions (though of course the first one has an additional "IPython" "layer").
I know I've got a working solution, but the interactive version would be a time saver and I would like to understand why there's a difference.

Thank you for your time and help!!

Comment: Are you using `%run` or `%prun`?

Comment: if he's profiling a python file run as a script, then `%prun` won't work here, i don't think.

Answer (score 0):

`%run` has some options for profiling. Actually from the docs for `%prun`:

> If you want to run complete programs under the profiler's control, use
>   `%run -p [prof_opts] filename.py [args to program]` where prof_opts
>   contains profiler specific options as described here.

Is probably a better way to do it.